# Pagination in KNIME

Tags: web, xpath, pagination, screen-scraping, knime

How to mark pagination in the XPath node in KNIME when I have a button for "show more"?

Comment: This depends on how new content is added to the page. Traditional "click and reload", or AJAX-style.

Comment: Maybe AJAX, it appends more results.

Comment: In case of JS-based websites, you can go with the Selenium Nodes: https://seleniumnodes.com (disclaimer: I’m one author of these nodes)

Comment: They are paid, and I am doing purely pro-bono stuff, for scientific purposes.

Comment: Yes, they are paid.